# Identifying Difference in string using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, difference

I Have 2 stings (sentences) and I would like to identify specific difference in both strings (sentences) when they do not match.

My sample code is below

```
my $diffpara1 = "This is paragraph 1";

my $diffpara2 = "This is paragraph 2 different from first paragraph";

my $samepara1 = "This is paragraph is same";

my $samepara2 = "This is paragraph is same";

print (($diffpara1 eq $diffpara2) ? '<span style="background-color: green">Matching</span>' : '<span style="background-color: red">Not Matching</span>');

print "<br/>".(($samepara1 eq $samepara2) ? '<span style="background-color: green">Matching</span>' : '<span style="background-color: red">Not Matching</span>');
```

The result for the above code is:

[image: Sample Output]

The above only indicates if the strings (sentences) match or if the strings (sentences) doesn't match. But I would like to generate an output that indicates what is different in both the strings (sentence).

Example output that I want (**BOLD** the difference):

> This is paragraph 1
>  This is paragraph **2 different from first
>   paragraph**

I am not sure if we can use REGEX to obtain the required output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And what should print for `This is text` and `This is word`?

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, there are some Perl modules that do this already -- have you searched CPAN? I've used Text::WordDiff in the past: https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::WordDiff

Comment: Thanks @ialarmedalien I tried `Text::WordDiff` module and it worked. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Text::WordDiff](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::WordDiff). You can output the differences as HTML, with deleted and inserted sections marked up with the `<del>` and `<ins>` tags respectively. A quick example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10";
use Text::WordDiff;

my $diffpara1 = "This is paragraph 1";
my $diffpara2 = "This is paragraph 2 different from first paragraph";

# output the difference between the lines as HTML, on two lines:
my $diff = word_diff \$diffpara1, \$diffpara2, { STYLE => 'HTMLTwoLines' };

say $diff;
```

output:

```
<div class="file"><span class="hunk">This is paragraph </span><span class="hunk"><del>1</del></span></div>
<div class="file"><span class="hunk">This is paragraph </span><span class="hunk"><ins>2 different from first paragraph</ins></span></div>
```

Identical lines:

```
my $samepara1 = "This is paragraph is same";
my $samepara2 = "This is paragraph is same";
my $diff2 = word_diff \$samepara1, \$samepara2, { STYLE => 'HTMLTwoLines' };
say $diff2;
```

output:

```
<div class="file"><span class="hunk">This is paragraph is same</span></div>
<div class="file"><span class="hunk">This is paragraph is same</span></div>
```

There are numerous different output options (save as plain text, save as html, save it to a file, save to a variable, etc.) and you can easily configure the html version to show the inserted and deleted text in different colours, in bold, or however you want using the almighty power of css.

Comment: Thanks @ialarmedalien i trid the example above and it worked.